# How to write a custom `@Html.Partial()` method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create a custom `@Html.Partial()` method.

**Use Case**

I have a .cshtml page where in I have multple sections like below

```
<!-- EDUCATION -->
@Html.Partial("Templates/Create/Modules/Education")

<!-- JOBS -->
@Html.Partial("Templates/Create/Modules/Jobs")
```

I want to be able to create a custom `.Partial()` method. Something on the likes of this

```
@Html.CustomPartial("Templates/Create/Modules/Jobs", "jobs", "edit")
```

where in the last two parameters are `module id` and `action type id` respectively. Using these values I will make a decision in my `CustomPartial` what I need to show in the output.

I am not sure how to go about this one. Please advice.

Or if someone can point me to the source code of the `Html.Partial` that too would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can already do this using the overload of `@Html.Partial()` that accepts a `ViewDataDictionary`

```
@Html.Partial("Templates/Create/Modules/Jobs", new ViewDataDictionary { { "module", someValue }, {"edit", anotherValue }})
```

Then in the partial

```
@if(ViewData["module"] == someValue)
{
  // do something
}
else
{
  // do something else
}
```

And if your still interested, [here is the source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/PartialExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RenderModule(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                             string partialViewName, 
                                             string moduleName,
                                             string actionType)
    {
        var isAccessAllowed = _someService.someMethod(userId, moduleName, actionType);    
        if (isAccessAllowed)
        {
            return helper.Partial(partialViewName);
        }
        else
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you intend to do it this way (that sort of logic does not belong in a html helper), why not use `@Html.Action()` which calls a child action method where you can perform the validation in the controller and return a corresponding view?

Comment: Nice. Thanks again, will think about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
      @Html.Partial("../Partial_views/_Menu_creation", new ViewDataDictionary { { "Type", 
     "Menu" }, { "Menu", "Dimensions" }, { "Active", "Yes" }, { "Icon", "icon-1" }, { 
     "data-hide", "" } })

In partial view
      @if (ViewData["Type"] == "Menu")
      {
         @if (ViewData["Active"] == "Yes")
          {
             <a data-check='@ViewData["Menu"]' role="button" class="active-menu">
               <b class='@ViewData["Icon"]'></b>
               <span>@ViewData["Menu"]</span>
            </a>
       }
       else
       {



    }
     }
     @if (ViewData["Type"] == "Heading")
     {
     }

This is working
```

Comment: Can you update the formatting and give an explanation of what you changed to help OP